# What can be the parameters to char getenv(const char *name);?

Tags: c, macos, unix, system, environment-variables

I looked over various documentation on `getenv()`, all they describe is how to use it and what it does i.e environment variable whose name is specified as argument.

But, I am trying to find the complete list or atleast as many as possible which can be used with `getenv()`

I know few like,

```
MANPATH
HOSTNAME
PATH
INFOPATH
PKG_CONFIG_PATH
USER
```

Can somebody help me extend this list?

Comment: The list is likely to be very long indeed. Some might say "infinitely long" I currently have over 200 environment variables set. In a Terminal window, issue the `env` command to see what you have set. Do you have an actual programming problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: Surely this is on topic as asks about a C function - the answer might involve  otherthings

Comment: It looks on-topic to me. If open-ended. (I'm not a close-voter on this one)

Comment: I understand that its infinite list. I have never played with env variables. I am trying to get user current session information like user name, user id, etc.

Comment: @Rahul - if you want user name then better to get from another call not getenv - if for a specific piece of info you need to ask what program sets it and use the name it uses - if you want a list of things see my **environ edit - so you need to be more specific in your question

Comment: @Mark - I was looking for something like http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/envvar.html list. Which you have already provided.

Comment: 2rahal which does not include many of your examples

Comment: @Mark - Yes I understand that. I just wanted extended list so that if I can use them directly in code.

Comment: Of course list can be big & I welcome if more can be added to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getenv queries your environment for any variable name. In Unix you can set any variable in the shell so there is no limit to what can be used (In OSX I think it is any Unicode string with no whitespace)
Thus there is no complete list.

To see what is in your environment type `env` in a Terminal window.

Or as per [Unix standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/envvar.html)

> The value of an environment variable is a string of characters. For a C-language program, an array of strings called the environment is made available when a process begins. The array is pointed to by the external variable environ, which is defined as:

```
extern char **environ;
```

Comment: Thank you.  I get most of the variables I intended to have from the link you gave.

Answer (score 2):

There *is* no complete list, because any user or any program can define their own environment variables with their own meanings. You might ask for the complete list of variables that a given program understands -- in that case often the man page for the program will list them.